# How to send notification inside onStartCommand method?

Tags: android, notifications, background, broadcastreceiver

I made notification and I wanted to send the notification when the app is destroyed, so I put the notification inside a `BroadcaseReceiver` that is the inside `onStartCommand` method of service, and I make it executes `onReceive` when ACTION_TIME_CHANGED, however, the `onStartCommand` is executed, but `onReceive()` is not.

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    NotificationManager notificationManager;
    Notification.Builder notification;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Service started",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(@Nullable Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Time is changed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        init_notification();

        BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();

                Toast.makeText(context,"Time is changed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,notification.build());
                }

            }
        };

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);


        registerReceiver(receiver,intentFilter);

        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `MyService` class like this and let me know if it works.

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    NotificationManager notificationManager;
    Notification.Builder notification;
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)    
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        init_notification();
        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();

                Toast.makeText(context,"Time is changed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,notification.build());
                }

            }
        };

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(ACTION_TIME_CHANGED);

        registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Service started",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(@Nullable Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Time is changed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(receiver != null)    
          unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }
}
```

Comment: it shows an error
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Lzu324VBxht7SQoDMCEsXMReKrIOtWCr/view

Comment: I have updated the answer. By the way `init_notification()` method is written in your code. I have just copied it. If it's not there, delete that line.